# How to paste same value that meets conditions in new column in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

EDIT: accidentally had stimulus defined on the line of the code block so it was not showing up.

I have an issue that I'm not sure how to solve. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Basically, I have some data that I want to reformat in a way that takes a value that meets certain criteria from an individual cell and repeats it for each of the instances of a given condition.

Below I have a recreated toy example of the issue:

```
stimulus <- c("instructions","happy", "sad", "anger", "instructions", "happy", "sad", "anger", "instructions", "happy", "sad", "anger")
test_part <- c("comprehension", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "comprehension", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "comprehension", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion")
answer <- c(0, 1,3,5,0, 7,2,1, 0, 1,7,2)
condition <- c(NA, "angry", "angry", "angry", NA, "happy", "happy", "happy", NA, "sad", "sad", "sad")
id <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
mydata<-data.frame(id, condition, test_part, stimulus, answer)
head(mydata)
```

Here is the set up of the data:

```
> head(mydata)
  id condition     test_part     stimulus answer
1  1      <NA> comprehension instructions      0
2  1     angry       emotion        happy      1
3  1     angry       emotion          sad      3
4  1     angry       emotion        anger      5
5  1      <NA> comprehension instructions      0
6  1     happy       emotion        happy      7
```

I want a new column for each of the emotion "test_part" rows that repeats the stimulus answer that matches the condition. So, for example, I first want a new variable called AngryRating that takes the "answer" value from the row that has anger in it and repeats that value for each of the rows of that condition (anger) and then repeats the next "answer" value from the anger row for the next condition (happy) and so forth

Here is what I tried to do to get the correct value into a new column/variable:

```
mydata$AngryRating <- ifelse(mydata$stimulus == "anger" & mydata$test_part == "emotion",
                                paste0(mydata$answer), NA)
head(mydata)
```

```
> head(mydata)
  id condition     test_part     stimulus answer AngryRating
1  1      <NA> comprehension instructions      0        <NA>
2  1     angry       emotion        happy      1        <NA>
3  1     angry       emotion          sad      3        <NA>
4  1     angry       emotion        anger      5           5
5  1      <NA> comprehension instructions      0        <NA>
6  1     happy       emotion        happy      7        <NA>
```

But here, I'm only getting one value for condition == anger, test_part == emotion, and stimulus == anger. But I want that 5 value pasted for all the rows where condition == anger (and the next anger value for all rows where condition == happy).

Like this:

```
answerFormatted <-c(NA,5,5,5,NA,1,1,1, NA,2,2,2)
mydesireddata<-data.frame(id, condition, test_part, stimulus, answer, answerFormatted)
head(mydesireddata)
```

```
> head(mydesireddata)
  id condition     test_part     stimulus answer answerFormatted
1  1      <NA> comprehension instructions      0              NA
2  1     angry       emotion        happy      1               5
3  1     angry       emotion          sad      3               5
4  1     angry       emotion        anger      5               5
5  1      <NA> comprehension instructions      0              NA
6  1     happy       emotion        happy      7               1
```

It may be the case that I need to loop or something, but I'm just not sure how to get the value to repeat under the correct conditions in a way that is efficient at all. Again, any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: You forgot to define `stimulus`.

Comment: Thank you @MartinGal! I fixed it.

Comment: are your test_part blocks that should get the same AngryRating always separated by comprehension / instruction blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure, if this is what you are looking for. You may use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(id, grp = cumsum(is.na(condition)), grp2 = is.na(condition)) %>% 
  mutate(
    AngryRating = ifelse(
      str_extract(condition, "^.{3}") == str_extract(stimulus, "^.{3}"), 
      answer, NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(AngryRating, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp, grp2)
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 12 × 7
      id condition test_part     stimulus     answer grp2  AngryRating
   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>         <chr>         <dbl> <lgl>       <dbl>
 1     1 NA        comprehension instructions      0 TRUE           NA
 2     1 angry     emotion       happy             1 FALSE           5
 3     1 angry     emotion       sad               3 FALSE           5
 4     1 angry     emotion       anger             5 FALSE           5
 5     1 NA        comprehension instructions      0 TRUE           NA
 6     1 happy     emotion       happy             7 FALSE           7
 7     1 happy     emotion       sad               2 FALSE           7
 8     1 happy     emotion       anger             1 FALSE           7
 9     1 NA        comprehension instructions      0 TRUE           NA
10     1 sad       emotion       happy             1 FALSE           7
11     1 sad       emotion       sad               7 FALSE           7
12     1 sad       emotion       anger             2 FALSE           7
```

What is happening here?

- First we group the data by `id` (based on the assumption, that different `id`s shouldn't be mixed) and blocks of data with consecutive test_parts (these are separated by conditions with `NA`s).
- We extract the value from the `answer` column, if the condition and the stimulus are matching. Since `angry` and `anger` aren't the same, we only compare the first three letters.
- Finally we apply this answer (`AngryRating`) to all entry in the same block (as defined above).